# Is set of integrals of continuous functions in $C[0,1]$ totally bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness, sequence-of-function, equicontinuity

Let $M$ be a bounded subset of $C[0,1]$ with supremum metric. Let $$C'=\left\{ F:[0,1] \to\mathbb R: F(x) = \int f(t) \, dt\right\}. $$ Show that $C'$ is totally bounded.

I started to do it with the `characterisation of compact metric space`  but I ended up finding that f is compact and I couldn't find a way to reach F to be compact...

Comment: This is an immediate application  of Arzela - Ascoli Theorem.

Comment: You refer to something called $F(x)$ without anything called $x. \qquad$

Comment: x is ofcource an element of [0,1],since F is a function from [0,1] to set of reals..

Comment: You also never mention $M$ after defining it.

Comment: This question has been answered before on this site.

Comment: Can you send the link to the answer.....

Comment: The question is given like that.... Its quite complicated way of questioning!!!